# Not changing the orientation which has entered

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

in my app you can enter an activity in both orientations but I want that in one screen, if you have entered with one orientation, you cant change to the other until you exit that activity

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the system that your activity will handle a configuration change, such as an orientation change.

Edit your `<activity>` element in your manifest file to include the `android:configChanges` attribute with a value that represents the configuration you want to handle:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:configChanges="orientation">
```

When your activity starts -lets say on `onStart()` or `onResume()`, capture what is the current orientation, so you can use that value during the execution of the activity to make any decision based on that

```
private int initialOrientation;
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    initialOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

}
```

Then in the activity, define a listener for the configuration listener, in which you set the orientation to what it was, and the orientation will stay as it is.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(initialOrientation);
}
```

Comment: @DavidLamasJimenez please see the edits. if you add a break point  in `onConfigurationChanged` is the execution even going inside?

Comment: It continue the same, it can rotate